# Following Odoo Tutorial - Getting Nowhere - Seems Normal

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

Dear Programming Community,

Hello, this is dog. Please read my sufferings as I try and learn Odoo. 
I will try to draw ASCII art diagrams of my code that I have so you can emulate the
package structure and link to a GitHub account so you can follow along with the horror
I have encountered while trying to follow an Odoo tutorial.

The project code is located on GitHub at the following URL: https://github.com/avoidreality/OdooHorrorShow

A primitive ASCII art drawing follows this sentence. The words between brackets are folders. The asterisks
are files. The lines connecting the folders emulate the folder hierarchy.

The project structure is so:

```
[test_odoo]
   |
   |
  [add-ons]
     |
     |
    [openacademy]
        |
        |
     [controllers]
       *__init__.py
       *controllers.py
       |
       |
     [demo]
       *demo.xml
       |
       |
     [models]
       *__init__.py
       *models.py
       |
       |
     [security]
       *ir.model.access.csv
       |
       |
     [views]
       *openacademy.xml
       *templates.xml
       *views.xml
     *__init__.py
     *__manifest__.py
```

I have followed the tutorial up to this point: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/howtos/backend.html#relational-fields

So far I have no idea what I should be expecting to see or where I should see anything. I am assuming I am going to see something
on a web page as some of the files edited have HTML tags. Does anyone have any clues about this?

The files that I have modified for the example are as follows:

```
 - OdooHorrorShow/test_odoo/addons/openacademy/models/models.py
 - OdooHorrorShow/test_odoo/addons/openacademy/demo/demo.xml
 - OdooHorrorShow/test_odoo/addons/openacademy/__manifest__.py
 - OdooHorrorShow/test_odoo/addons/openacademy/views/openacademy.xml
```

I do have an odoo 11 server running on my localhost. When I go to the localhost and enter the odoo port number I am immediately brought to this page: http://localhost:8069/web

Regards,

user3870315

Comment: Learning Odoo has a very steep learning curve, don't give up! You are on the right path.

Comment: Yes, don't give up!

Comment: Thank-you guys for the encouragement. That is amazing. Most people just want to "watch the world burn".

Answer (score 2):

There's almost nothing to see (graphically) to the point you have reached so far.

If your module is correctly installed, you can see its data sheet.

1. Go to the `Apps` menu. On the upper left, you'll see a search bar
   with a `Apps [x]` tag and a magnifying glass symbol with a plus sign
   inside.
2. Click on the `[x]` to make the `Apps [x]` tag disappear.
3. Search for `openacademy` on the search bar.

But as you can see, there are no menus nor views in the module yet.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, I learned how to install  my own module over the weekend by following a Udemy tutorial from Packt. There is a helpful German narrator that pronounces dot pie files as "pooh" files. :D Thank-you sir for the help with the tutorial code. I will try and load the module and keep following along with the documentation/tutorial.

Comment: Anytime, don't be afraid to ask.

Comment: I think your answer could be marked as correct if you explain how to upload a module to an Odoo server.

Comment: That sounds like extortion to me, beware your manners. Either mark it as correct or don't, it doesn't matter to me.

Comment: Anyway, just upload the files and add your `addons` dir to the `addons-path` switch or config option.

Comment: Well I do not think the you answered the question. I really do not appreciate the accusations of extortion. I do not think that is fair. You are really irritating me.

Comment: Thanks for saying "do not be afraid" and "don't give up you are on the right path" and then accusing me of a serious federal crime for making a comment to your answer. That is absurd and you should be ashamed of yourself sir.